# span element style not applying

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a div that act as a console. It record the activity on the site. I display message in it and to apply color to the text I use `<span>` elements with CSS classes.

My CSS classes

```css
.consoleError{    <---- dynamic prepend
    color: #f00;
}​

.consoleGood{      <---- dynamic prepend
    color: #2aff01;
}
```

The JavaScript that prepend(Jquery) the stings:

```
$('#console').prepend('<span class="consoleError">ERREUR : </span>' + data[i] + '<br>');
                        }

$('#console').prepend('<span class="consoleGood"> Status: ' + data[0] + '</span> Requête: ' + action + ' Conteneur:' +container+ '<br>');
```

I use prepend to insert them at the top;

Now the problem is that when an error occur the "consoleError" class is taking effect I see it live in red;

The other class "consoleGood" spans are inserted before I can actually view them because of the time it take me to get to the console.

So I'm wondering why one span CSS is working and not the other that was inserted prior to activating the display of "#console" element?

Anyone know what is wrong here?

Comment: I think we need more information and example to solve this

Comment: It is not clear what you are asking. Is it possible that you could create a simple example that shows the problem you need to solve using something like JSFiddle or CodePen?

Comment: Well i fixed it by moving the class up in my CSS right above the class for #console Scrollbar and its working now.